# Class method as default __init__ argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor

I am trying to set a default function in the class constructor. Caveat is that the function is from within the same class.

```
Class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, filename, file_rename_func=filename_parser):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file_rename_func = file_rename_func

    def filename_parser(self, filename)
        return filename + '. Hi, StackOverflow!'
```

This keeps giving me the error:
`NameError: name 'filename_parser' is not defined`

If I were to instead have the `__init__` function look like this:

```
def __init__(self, filename, file_rename_func=self.filename_parser):
```

I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

How can I get around this issue if I must have this done in the constructor?

Comment: At the time you’re writing this, the method doesn’t exist yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this as follows:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, filename, file_rename_func=None):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file_rename_func = file_rename_func or self.filename_parser

    def filename_parser(self, filename)
        return filename + '. Hi, StackOverflow!'
```

this works on the basis that file_rename_func should be a function object and thus evaluate to true. Thus this value is used, when file_rename_func  it evaluates to false and the second value is used.

EDIT:

using self will not fix the issue since self is a parameter to the function __init__ (and when the default value is calculated it's not known what self is(think of *self* as just any parameter).

Comment: wont "file_rename_func or self.filename_parser" return a boolean?

Comment: Nope, you can try in console `print(None or 5)`, you will see it prints 5

Comment: @Mitchnoff: Nope: The result of an `and`/`or` chain in Python is the last value evaluated, not just `0`/`1` or `false`/`true` like it is in C/C++/Java. So for `or`, it's the first truthy value seen, or the last value in the chain; if `file_rename_func` is truthy, the expression evaluates to that, otherwise it evaluates to `self.filename_parser` (regardless of whether it's truthy or falsy, though bound methods are definitionally truthy).

Comment: I guess you learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things to make this work:

1. Define `filename_parser` *first* so you can refer to it (unqualified) when defining the default for `__init__`
2. Decorate it as a `staticmethod` so it is always invoked without passing `self` (since you don't *use* `self` anyway)

The following will do that:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod                   # Add staticmethod decorator so self never passed
    def filename_parser(filename):  # Remove self from prototype
        return filename + '. Hi, StackOverflow!'

    def __init__(self, filename, file_rename_func=filename_parser):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file_rename_func = file_rename_func
```

Note that as written, this will only work on Python 3.10, the first version where `staticmethod` objects themselves are callable *without* invoking the descriptor protocol on them first (by looking them up on a class or instance of the class). Pre 3.10, it's a little uglier, as you have to manually extract the underlying function for the default argument, while leaving it a `staticmethod` otherwise. The only change is to the prototype of `__init__`, which becomes:

```
    def __init__(self, filename, file_rename_func=filename_parser.__func__):
```

explicitly looking up the wrapped function inside the `staticmethod` object.

Comment: If this function can be a staticmethod one could ask why this function needs to be defined in this class. But still a neat solution!

Comment: Note: This only works because `filename_parser` *could* be a `staticmethod`. There are other techniques available if it actually needs access to a `self`, but they're complicated/weird enough that I'd just recommend [Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464298/364696) if that's the case.

Comment: @RobinDillen: Yeah, that's an issue with *all* `@staticmethod`s; they don't even get a reference to the class they were invoked against, so for all practical purposes it's just a namespacing trick to group functions that are logically related to the class but not actually concerned with the class itself (nor any instances thereof) in any programmatic sense. That might apply here (if a non-default function is passed, it doesn't get any information about the instance either), but it might not (maybe the default case does rely on instance info). Depends on the OP's use case.